# No AuthInfo found for name always

Tags: salesforcedx, sfdx-plugin, sfdx-error

Is there a way to full reinstall sfdx? How to delete settings?

I am creating an sfdx project, auth in org and with retrieve command i am  getting  No AuthInfo found for name with name of another org user. All scratches deleted, delfaut user deleted. So to use any command i need  specify the user manually. How can  i remove that?

I have used " sfdx force:alias:set " with no username and now just No AuthInfo found for name for undefined

What can i do? I can use most commad with -u username, but i cennot create package: it gives error Invalid character in header content ["getApiVersion"]

Answer (score 1):

So I had the same issue these days and the only step I did to pass through is activating an option called **Enable Unlocked Packages and Second-Generation Managed Packages** inside the **Dev Hub** settings.

Answer (score 1):

The issue for me was the lack of permissions on the user performing the operation. I was using a Limited Access User Profile for a CI/CD job and the following permissions are required:

- Create and Update Second-Generation Packages
- Promote a package version to released

Answer (score 0):

If the Dev Hub org doesn't have its "Unlocked and 2GP Packages" option enabled, you would get the error message ***Invalid character in header content ["getApiVersion"]***.  You may want to check that.

Answer (score 0):

Enable Unlocked Packages and Second-Generation Managed Packages inside the Dev Hub settings solve my problem.

The think is the color is blue when disabled and you may think that its already enabled.

I check the same setting 4 times and I cannot recognize it. I thought that its enabled and I try to solve my problem from different places.